# IBM Lotus Notes FTSearch = seems to do a contains, is there a way to do a equals

Tags: lotus-notes

Hi I am trying to do a Full Text Search on a field

FIELD dog = "Labrador"

but it is returning documents with 
dog = "Labrador retriever" and 
dog = "Chocolate Labrador"

It seems = acts like contains not equals.?

Is there a way to make this be exact or do I need to do something like:

FIELD dog="Labrador" AND NOT (FIELD dog="Cholcolate") AND NOT (FIELD dog="Retriever" )

Answer (score 4):

Full text search works against a pre-built word index, not against the actual items.  So of course it does a Contains search. If you want to do exact-match searching, than you need to use the Search method instead of FTSearch.

Answer (score 3):

Some help on the keywords for full-text searching can be found here:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.notes85.help.doc%2Fsch_refine_query_r.html

Essentially the equals sign is the same as saying CONTAINS.

Comment: I don't know what IBM/Lotus were thinking with this syntax, but it seemed to be created in a room with 1 or 2 guys over a weekend (with too much beer and pizza), and these guys had no contact with the outside world.

Answer (score 0):

How about trying to find only documents which don't contain a space? That would avoid "Labrador Retriever" when searching for "Labrador", right?

```
FIELD dog="Labrador" AND NOT (FIELD dog=" ")
```

Of course, this only works for when you want just one word, so it's not real flexible.